# How to get the closest items in the Sitecore tree?

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api

I would like get the closest list of items, if the items starts with particular name in the sitecore tree.

[image]

In the tree, if i am in **Item** page, i have to take all the closest items start with **Item**
ItemDummy1
ItemDummy2
ItemDummy3
ItemDummy4

Do we have any fastest query to fetch the list?

Comment: Do you want to get the items based on the current item name? it would be good if you can explain it a little more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitecore query functions make it possible to perform Boolean operations with Items in query expressions and apply extra conditions to the query.

You can use `startswith` function:

```
   Function: startswith(s1:string,s2:string):bool
```

**Description:** Indicates whether s1 starts with substring s2. The comparison is case-sensitive.

**Query Example:**

```
query:/sitecore/content/home//*[startswith(@@name, 'Item')]
```

Returns child Items of the Home Item whose name starts with `Item` .

Comment: If the items are from the same template, you can also filter by template name or template id

Comment: Traversing the entire content tree like this WILL lead to performance issues. I would not recommend following this approach, instead use the ContentSearch API to perform the query.